# I Have Some Error. I dont know what is :/ (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I Wrote this for a Video Club (HomeWork)

```
CREATE TABLE FILMS (
TITLE VARCHAR (35),
GENDER VARCHAR (15),
MANAGERVARCHAR (20),
ACTORS VARCHAR (90),
COPYS INT)
CREATE TABLE LOAN (
ID_LOAN INT,
ID_PARTNER INT,
FILM_LOAN VARCHAR (35),
DATE_LOAN DATE,
ID_COPY INT
) 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LESS_COPY
AFTER INSERT ON LOAN 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE FILM SET FILMS.COPYS = FILMS.COPYS - 1
WHERE FILMS.TITLE = LOAN.FILM_LOAN
END
```

Oracle drop me This

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

I Need help to fix this :(

Comment: Missing semi colons at the end of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Query the `USER_ERRORS` view to see the compilation errors.

In this case I note that your trigger body says `UPDATE FILM ...` but the table name is `FILMS`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, no ";" at end of your update statement